# Object in array is undefined in vue

Tags: vue.js

I need help as the array “items1” works when “console.log(this.items1)”
However, it is undefined when “console.log(this.items1[0])”. How can I solve this? I really have no idea what is going. Ultimately, I want to gather item.text whenever user selects the tab from v-tabs. Using item.text, I am able to filter the data in db. Is there a way to gather the user input whenever user selects tab?

```
 <template>
  <v-layout>
    <v-container flat  grid-list-lg>
      <v-layout row wrap class="flex_box feature_products"> 
        <v-flex xs12>
          <h2 class="text-xs-center feature_products_title">Check Our <span>Delicious Menu</span></h2>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex xs12>
            <v-card>
                <v-toolbar flat>
                    <template v-slot:extension>

                        <v-tabs v-model="model" centered slider-color="yellow">
                          <v-tab v-for="(item, index) in items1" :key="index" :href="`#tab-${index}`">
              {{ item.text }}
                          </v-tab>
                        </v-tabs>
                    </template>
                </v-toolbar>


                <v-tabs-items v-model="model">
                    <v-tab-item v-for="(item, index) in items1" :key="index" :value="`tab-${index}`">
                            <!-- your this code displays the product information, but there is no way to filter the product by category -->
              <v-layout row wrap class="flex_box feature_products">
                            <v-flex xs12 sm3 md3 lg3 xl2  class="flex_item" v-for="(product,index) in products" :key="index">
                              <v-card flat v-if="product.category_name == item.text">
                                  <v-card class="overlay_container flex_wrap  pa-2">
                                    <v-img :src="product.image" contain></v-img>
                                    <div style="width:100%;" class="flex_bottom text-xs-center pb-2">
                                      <h3 class="headline text-xs-center grey--text text--darken-3">{{product.item_name}}</h3>
                                      <h4 class="grey--text text--darken-3">{{currency}}{{product.price}}</h4>                                           
                                    </div>

                                    <v-card class="overlay">                       
                                        <h2 style="vertical-align:middle;">{{product.item_name}}</h2>                        
                                        <v-list class="details">
                                        <v-list-tile-action>
                                            <v-btn style="width:100%"  :to="'/product/' + product.id">Details</v-btn>
                                        </v-list-tile-action>
                                        <v-list-tile-action>
                                            <v-btn style="width:100%" class="main_color white--text" @click="addToCart(product)">Add To Cart</v-btn>
                                        </v-list-tile-action>
                                        </v-list>
                                    </v-card>   
                                  </v-card> 
                              </v-card>                         
                              <v-card v-else>
                              </v-card>
                            </v-flex>           
              </v-layout>           


                    </v-tab-item>
                </v-tabs-items>                         

            </v-card>

        </v-flex>

      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import firebase from "firebase";
  import moment from 'moment' 
  import db, {functions} from '@/firebase/init'
  import MenuNavbar from  '@/components/shop/navbar/MenuNavbar'
  export default {
    data(){
      // Show All Categories
      let ref = db.collection("item_categories");
      ref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
          if (change.type == "added") {
            let doc = change.doc;
            this.items1.push({

              icon: doc.data().category_icon,            
              text: doc.data().category_name,
              link:'CatProduct',
              category:doc.data().category_name,
                    text1: 'Category Name: ' + doc.data().category_name 
            });
          }
        });
      });
      return{   
          model:'tab-2',  // select your default tab here
        currency:null,
        products:[],
        cart:this.$store.getters.cart,
        items1:[],
      }

    },
    components: {
      MenuNavbar
    },
    methods: {
      productInCart(product) {
        const cartItems = this.cart
        for (let i = 0; i < cartItems.length; i++) {
          if (cartItems[i].product.id === product.id) {
            return i       
          }
        }
        return null
      },      
      addToCart(product, quantity){
        const index = this.productInCart(product)
        const productQuantity = (!quantity || quantity < 1) ? 1 : parseInt(quantity)
        if (index === null) {
          var items = {
              product: product,
              quantity: productQuantity
          }
          //this.$store.commit('catalog/updateCart', items)
          this.$store.commit('updateCart', items)
        }else {
          if(!quantity){
              // If item is already into the cart then add++ quantity                   
              this.$store.commit('increaseQuantity', index)

          }else{
              // When quantity updated manually
          }
        }        
      },
      removeCart(index){
        this.$store.commit('removeCart', index)     
      }, 
    },
    computed:{
      counter(){
        return this.$store.getters.counter 
      },

    },
    getTabText(text){
      return text
    },
    created(){
      var db = firebase.firestore();
      // Current Currency   
      db.collection("settings").doc('config').onSnapshot(doc =>{
        this.currency = doc.data().currency
      })
      console.log(this.items1[0])
      // Show All Items
      let cref = db.collection('items').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').where("featured", "==", true)

      cref.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
          if(change.type == 'added'){
            let doc = change.doc
            this.products.push({
              id:doc.id,
              item_name:doc.data().item_name,
              image:doc.data().image,
              category_name:doc.data().item_category,
              price:doc.data().price,
              quantity:doc.data().quantity,
              timestamp:moment(doc.data().timestamp).fromNow('lll')
            })
          }
        })
      })
    } 
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Do you call them consecutive?

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to help us find the problem. It might also help you find it yourself.

Comment: plz add a fiddle or pen for it so we can check where is the issue otherwise it is difficult to find

Comment: what do you mean consecutive? @HansFelixRamos